# How to to use different TCP socket connection for URLs that share the same address (URL)

Tags: okhttp

[Okhttp documentation](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Connections#addresses) states the following:

> URLs that share the same address may also share the same underlying TCP socket connection.

We need to use different TCP socket connection for URLs that share the same address (URL). Is there any configuration in okhttp client to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp doesn't yet have client-side load balancing, but there's a [tracking bug](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4530) for it that is prioritized.

Until that’s done you'll need to create multiple `OkHttpClients`, each with a different `ConnectionPool` instance. It’s clumsy and awkward but might get you unblocked until the load balancing feature is ready.